# Can I use an adapter to plug a 4 prong dryer into a welder outlet?

Tags: 240v, adapter

I have a welder outlet in my garage that I’ll probably never use. I was wondering if I can use an adapter like this to connect a dryer with four prongs:

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07P93HF1P/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_glt_fabc_X4665SV730DE18T6R3ND](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07P93HF1P)

With an adapter like this, clearly there’s no neutral connected to the dryer + the breaker is 50amps vs the normal 30amps for a dryer.

Comment: What is the dryer model?  Do you have the manual?  It may need the neutral for the light or timer.  It may need a 30A breaker if it doesn't have it's own protection.  The documentation will help.

Comment: Off hand probably not good idea.  You might be lucky and cable for welder outlet is three wire plus ground, with neutral not connected.  Just need to change outlet and drop breaker down to 30 amp.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box for the welder outlet please?

Comment: Can't do it.  Dryers need neutral.  The welder outlet only provides ground.  Also the dryer needs a 30A breaker, the welder has a 50A breaker.

Comment: By the way, that adapter is illegal, and is sold by dodgy people, probably beyond the reach of our laws.  That's how Amazon works unfortunately; they have no liability for dangerous junk they sell.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I don’t have a photo of the inside at the moment but when I did open it, I saw an extra wire capped off (black with a white line). I assume this is unused neutral in the box. The cables connected to the welder socket were two other blacks (one solid black and another had a red stripe) plus a ground wire. Presumably I can replace the socket with a 14-30 with the neutral connected and switch out the breaker to 30amps?

Comment: @shyamster -- can you turn the breaker off, then open up the receptacle and check for electrical continuity from the black/white wire to the bare ground wire?

Comment: Can you see the other end of the black with white in the breaker panel?  Is it there, is it connected to neutral or capped off?